# BizTalk 2009 FTP cannot retrieve files with spaces in the filename?

Tags: ftp, biztalk, space, biztalk-2009

I was having a little trouble with reading files using the FTP adapter. Several warnings and errors were found in the application log, and it basically boiled down to this message:

> A stream read or write operation failed because the stream is in an error state.

Upon inspecting the log, I was surprised to find:

```
< 125 List started.
< BEBI           827693 24/09/14 15:53:51 *STMF      mes9_ corrigido2.csv
< 250 List completed.
> TYPE I
< 200 Representation type is binary IMAGE.
> PORT 192,168,205,82,213,48
< 200 PORT subcommand request successful.
> RETR corrigido2.csv
```

so, there is just a single file with name `mes9_ corrigido2.csv` (notice the space) and BizTalk tries to retrieve a file `corrigido2.csv`. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: It was an issue in BizTalk 2006 for which they issued a hotfix (https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/932886?wa=wsignin1.0) maybe that issue has come back.  Is your BizTalk 2009 fully patched to CU 6?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf sorry for the late reply. I'm fairly confident we've never actually installed updates for our BTS2009. We're going to patch to CU6 tomorrow, I'll let you know how the FTP adapter behaves after that.

Comment: Did the CU6 resolve the problem?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf apologies for never reporting back on this. We had tried to install CU6. The setup reported a successful installation, but when I checked the biztalk version it was the old version. We had lots of trouble with biztalk then, took us days to fix. So I can't say if it would have fixed the FTP problem.